# Understanding thrown expression of class E

Tags: java, exception

Assume that the expression `e` can throw `E`. Is it true that the expression can also throw any of superclass of `E`?

The [JLS Exception Descriptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) didn't mention it.

> A throw statement (§14.18) whose thrown expression has static type E
>   and is not a final or effectively final exception parameter can throw
>   E or any exception class that the thrown expression can throw.

Couldn't you explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JLS quote + the example following it :

> For example, the statement throw new java.io.FileNotFoundException();
>   can throw java.io.FileNotFoundException only. **Formally, it is not the
>   case that it "can throw" a subclass or superclass of
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException**.

If you write `throw new E ()`, this expression can only throw `E` or exceptions that are thrown by the constructor of `E`.

Therefore, the answer is no, the expression can't throw any supertype of `E`. The only way it can throw a supertype of `E` is if the constructor of `E` throws an exception that is a superclass of `E`.